# How to get and print string in java

Tags: java

I can get and print the integer value in java but I am confuse how to get  and print string. Can someone help

```
package hello;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int integer;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Integer");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        integer = sc.nextInt();

        sc.close();


        System.out.println("you entered : " +integer);


    }
}
```

Program output

```
Please Enter Integer
5
you entered : 5
```

I am stuck in this program. I don't understand how to get string and print on screen

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int name;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name");


        name = sc.nextInt(); 

         sc.close();

         System.out.println("Your name"+name);


    }
}
```

Comment: sc.nextLine() ?

Comment: Change type of `name` to `String`, and then `name = sc.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your type value `name` from `int` to `String`. And replace `sc.nextInt()` by `sc.nextLine()` or `sc.next()`.

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name");


    name = sc.nextLine();

    sc.close();

    System.out.println("Your name " + name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sc.nextLine() for reading string inputs
or
sc.next()  (But this will read only a word before it encounters a space)

You can also use InputStreamReader for this purpose

eg.

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in()));

String input = br.readLine();

Answer (score 0):

name = sc.nextInt(); doesn't work for strings, only for integers, you should use sc.nextline instead.
And also you have to change int name to String name, due to other type of variable.

Your code should look like this:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name");


        name = sc.nextLine(); 

         sc.close();

         System.out.println("Your name"+name);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change int name to string name and use sc.nextLine()

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name");


        name = sc.nextLine(); 

         sc.close();

         System.out.println("Your name"+name);


    }
}
```